# .htaccess rewrite rule applies wrong

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm new to htaccess and i want to use `RewriteRule` in order to make urls more friendly but i have a problem.
Here is my htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule download/(.*)$ download.php?file=$1 [NC]
  RewriteRule download/view/(.*)/(.*)$ download_view.php?name=$1&id=$2 [NC]
</IfModule>
```

Whatever i navigate to `localhost/download/view/test/2/` for example, it appears as the first url `localhost/download/test/`

How to fix this ?

Comment: The last matching rule applies. If you want to mark a different than the actually last matching rule as the last one, you need to use the `L` or `LAST` flag for it. Take care then when the URI changes (as it does here), it will be re-injected into the rewrite-rule-loop. However the rewritten rules do not start with `download/` again, so you should not run into any further problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn around the order of those two rules, so that the more specialized one comes first. Then use the additional `L` flag to prevent further rewriting after a match:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule download/view/(.*)/(.*)$ download_view.php?name=$1&id=$2 [NC,L]
  RewriteRule download/(.*)$ download.php?file=$1 [NC]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: In case of flipping, the L rule is not needed in this particular example because the substituted URI is passed along to the more RewriteRules which do not match any longer. This also explains the initial behavior. My comment above might have been misleading because it talks about the `L` flag only.

Comment: It certainly is true, that the `L` flag is not _required_ in this specific example. I added it for the sake of completeness.

Comment: It can help in sparing additional rules, so here exactly one. The third and fourth rules are then checked for anyway. For completeness you could therefore suggest the `END` flag as rewriting is fully done.

Answer (score 2):

Your first rewrite-rule already changes the URI:

```
RewriteRule download/(.*)$ download.php?file=$1 [NC]
```

Therefore `localhost/download/view/test/2/` is already rewritten to `download.php?file=view/test/2/` and the second rule you intentionally want to match against does not match any longer:

```
RewriteRule download/view/(.*)/(.*)$ download_view.php?name=$1&id=$2 [NC]
```

This does not match `download.php?file=view/test/2/`.

So you can solve this, by doing the check for `download/view/...` first, by flipping those two:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule download/view/(.*)/(.*)$ download_view.php?name=$1&id=$2 [NC]
  RewriteRule download/(.*)$ download.php?file=$1 [NC]
</IfModule>
```

Always start with the most concrete/specific rule to rule out such problems. In more difficult cases, use `RewriteCond` to fine-tune when to apply a rewrite-rule.

I also suggest if you want to match at the beginning of the URI Paths, you should use the caret ("`^`") to mark the beginning in the regular expression:

```
  RewriteRule ^download/view/(.*)/(.*)$ download_view.php?name=$1&id=$2 [NC]
  RewriteRule ^download/(.*)$ download.php?file=$1 [NC]
```